# Booting mainline Linux kernel using device tree

Tags: c, linux-kernel, device-tree

I followed the following steps to build and flash my kernel on `QEMU`:

1. `make  ARCH=arm distclean`
2. `make ARCH=arm versatile_defconfig`
3. `make ARCH=arm menuconfig`
   here you need to enable below feature.
   Kernel Features  --->  [*] Use the `ARM EABI` to compile the kernel. (enable this).
4. `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi- uImage`
5. `qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -kernel arch/arm/boot/uImage -append "console=tty1"`
   Here you will get console saying that kernel panic. To avoid this pass your `rootfs` parameter.
   I guess you built rootfs from busybox if so try below command to boot system completely
6. `qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -kernel arch/arm/boot/uImage -initrd rootfs.img -append "root=/dev/ram mem=128M rdinit=/sbin/init"  -serial stdio`

On runtime, is kernel using a device tree to load the devices? If yes, how to confirm and where is the device tree located? (I need to make changes to the device tree file (.dts), but unable to find where is the file located) Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device-tree is located in `arch/arm/boot/dts/versatile-pb.dts`